# LibreOffice Writer (6.0.1.1): Turn off capitalization of first word

Tags: libreoffice

How to turn off capitalization of first word in LibreOffice Writer (6.0.1.1) ?

I tried to search for a checkbox under *Options → LibreOffice* and under *Options → LibreOffice → LibreOffice Write* but I didn't find a checkbox, which I'm likely to have missed.

Where did you turn this off?

Comment: Close Voters: ***This is on topic here on Ask Ubuntu.*** Do not close this as offtopic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn off capitalization of the first word of each sentence via **Tools → Autocorrect → Autocorrect options …**

[image: LO autocorrect options]

As noted at the bottom of the options tab, you can choose whether to apply the preference to existing text, and/or while typing new text:

```
[M]: Replace while modifying text
[T]: AutoCorrect while typing
```